# MySQL replication, prevent hackers from deleting the main database and the deletions being replicated

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have a setup of a master/slave MySQL servers.
My concern is that if the master database is hacked and the hackers delete tables or drop databases entirely, all the changes would be propagated to the slave, deleting it there as well.

Without using delays, what is a good way to prevent a hacker from also destroying my slave database?

Answer (score 1):

A MySQL Master/Slave setup works well when you want to create a fault-tolerant backend database for your web application or website.

If the master database fails, you can switch the application to use the slave. Therefore, this kind of approach can only work as a disaster recovery solution in case there is hardware or a software failure on the server hosting the master

However, like you mentioned, if a hacker deletes data from the master database, the changes will be quickly picked by the slave.

To be safe, I would advise you to create automated backup of the database on the slave. You can use a tool like **automysqlbackup**.

With the backup in place, you can restore your database to its original state from the slaves logs.

If you wish to design your own custom backup tool, make sure you include the time stamp of the backed up database so that you will be able to identify the most recent backup.

Also, if you feel like you don't have the time to build a secure and a fault tolerant database cluster for your application, I would advise you to go for self hosted MySQL solutions like ApsaraDB. With this kind of solution, your database is protected from DDoS, SQL injection and brute-force attacks.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove excessive permissions from your applications. This probably won't protect against a 'DELETE FROM table` unless you can remove that permission safely;

So, make backups as a point in time snapshot (mysqldump --single-transaction / lvm / xtrabackup), and save the binary log position. Save the binary log files (mapping to the recording noting master/relay logs are different) and ensure the binlog isn't purged off.

Test the recovery procedure in applying a binary log up to a specified point to make sure you've got the right information and procedure for when you need to use it.